# Conectar aplicação ao Postgresql?

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, ado.net

Rstou querendo conectar uma aplicação simples feita em C# à um banco de dados Postgresql, o que eu gostaria de saber é se o procedimento é parecido com o do Java, no qual eu tenho que criar uma classe conexão, uma classe com os get's e set's das entidades para manipular os dados?

Vi no Visual Studio que ele tem uma opção de **Connect to Database** e imaginei que o Visual Studio já fosse automatizado em relação à isso.

Comment: olha, dá uma olhada neste artigo: http://www.macoratti.net/14/07/ef6_pgsql1.htm

Answer (score 1):

A conexão é feita de forma similiar. No Java, você faz a conexão com o banco de dados através de JDBC. Arquivos .jar

No C# a conexão é feita através de ADO.NET. 
Assim como no Java, você vai precisar de um provider para acessar o banco de dados.
No caso, a DLL Npgsql.dll

Veja um simples exemplo de conexão abaixo.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Npgsql; //Referencia do provider de conexão do Postgresql.
```

public class NpgsqlUserManual
{
  public static void Main(String[] args)
  {
    NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=joe;Password=secret;Database=joedata;");
    conn.Open();
    conn.Close();
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Aqui está:
     string serverdb = "IP";
     string dbdb = "BaseDados";

```
 string userdb = "Username";
 string passdb = "Password";

 string connectionString = "Server=" + serverdb + ";Port=5432;UserID=" + userdb + ";password=" + passdb + ";Database=" + dbdb + ";";


public Boolean conecta()
{
    //Estabelece Ligações a Bases de Dados
    try
    {
        this.coneccao = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
        coneccao.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception )
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Erro de ligação");
      }
}
```